# Rotate a placetable/placefigure plus caption in ConTeXt?

Tags: floats, context, rotating

I've a large table, which I want to rotate to fit onto one page. My current solution looks like:

```
\placetable{some text}
{\rotate[rotation=90]{
  \starttable[...]
       ....
  \stoptable}}
```

But unfortunately this way only the table itself is rotate, not the caption.

Instead I want the table across the page to be in "landscape", whereas the header and footer won't be rotated. Something like:

```
\rotate[rotation=90]{
  \placetable{some text}
  {\starttable[...]
        ....
   \stoptable}}
```

such that the caption is rotated to and "under" the table (if the page is rotated to landscape in the viewer).

Update:

- example file with Taco Hoekwater's solution: https://gist.github.com/1034341
- now header and footer is missing.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Herbert: Normally, broad "concept" tags should be preferred to specific "command" tags.

Comment: @lockstep: rotating is the wrong tag for context!

Comment: @Herbert: {rotating} is ambiguous because it may stand for a) the general concept of "rotating" b) the LaTeX package of the same name. I'd still prefer to have one tag, however named. Maybe the naming question could be discussed at our meta site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In ConTeXt, all floats support rotation.

```
\placetable[90]{Caption}{Table content}
```

You can also try `180` and `270` to get other rotation angles.

Comment: @urso: I don't know whether it is documented or not. I guessed the solution by trial and error. I "knew" that such a basic feature must be supported. Now the only way to pass options to `\place<float>` is as parameters. The "obvious" choice for such parameters is `90`, `180`, `270` (similar arguments are also used for page rotation in `\definepapersize`). I tried it, and it worked. If you did not find it anywhere in the documentation, please add it to the [ConTeXt wiki](http://contextgarden.net)