# Is it even possible to rotate the whole 'text' frame on a ConTeXt document?

Tags: rotating, context-mkiv

This is 100% curiosity. Just came to mind if there's possible to rotate to some degree the whole `text` frame of a ConTeXt (Mark IV) document. I guess the `\rotate` command would do the trick, but I couldn't figure out how to apply it to the `text` frame (via `\setupframed`). I read on a question on this site that "all floats support rotation" ([Rotate a placetable/placefigure plus caption in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21116/rotate-a-placetable-placefigure-plus-caption-in-context)) but I really don't know if the `text` frame (or any other frame) count as float.

Any clue is hugely appreciated!

Comment: Not providing a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) is a sure way to discourage answers; and since ConTeXt is not as widely used as it probably should be, you are probably better off not discouraging any potential answerers.

Comment: What do you mean by `text` frame? Everything between `\starttext ... \stoptext`?

Comment: @jon: It's no use, and in this case it has no sense, to give a minimal example. It could be _anything_ written in ConTeXt.

Comment: @Aditya: Yes, as the text typeset area defined on [the wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layout). Not including pagenumbers, headers, footers and such.

Answer (score 5):

To rotate the typeset area, you need to define a new output routine. In the example below, I define a new routine that rotates each shipout box by 10 degrees. The `\showframe` is only for visualization purposes.

```
\unprotect
\unexpanded\def\page_shipout_rotatepage#1%
  {\writestatus{rotatepage}{rotating \the\realpageno}%
   \page_shipouts_normal{\rotate[rotation=10]{#1}}}

\installshipoutmethod{rotatepage}\page_shipout_rotatepage

\setuppaper
  [\c!method=rotatepage]

\protect

\showframe
\starttext
\dorecurse{10}{\input knuth\endgraf}
\stoptext
```

This is what the first page looks like:

[image]

Thanks to @Metafox, you can also implement this without using protected mode by using `\invokepagehandler{normal}` instead of `\page_shipouts_normal`.

```
\unexpanded\def\PageShipoutRotatePage#1%
  {\writestatus{rotatepage}{rotating \the\realpageno}%
   \invokepagehandler{normal}{\rotate[rotation=10]{#1}}}

\installshipoutmethod{rotatepage}\PageShipoutRotatePage

\setuppaper
  [method=rotatepage]


\showframe
\starttext
\dorecurse{10}{\input knuth\endgraf}
\stoptext
```

Comment: Kind of what I was imaging. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Aditya You can replace `\page_shipouts_normal{...}` with `\invokepagehandler{normal}{...}` to avoid the use of internal commands.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

```
\framed{\rotate[rotation=-34]{\framedtext{\input knuth\relax}}}
```

?