# Pdflscape.sty analogue for ConTeXt

Tags: context, landscape, page

Is there a way to rotate visually in PDF reader portrait page into landscape orientation in ConTeXt?

The idea is to have a document in portrait mode with, for example, a wide table rotated 90 degrees and rotate the page with the mentioned table too, retaining all page setups including size, header, footer, etc. Thus, what I need is an analogue of pdflscape.sty package, but for ConTeXt.

Comment: [`\adaptpapersize`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/adaptpapersize)?

Comment: This will change the whole page layout, if I am not mistaken. And, e.g. footer will appear not on the short, but on the long edge of a page.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then this should do the trick: https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Floating_Objects#Landscape_Floats_in_a_Portrait_Document

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate a placetable/placefigure plus caption in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21116/rotate-a-placetable-placefigure-plus-caption-in-context)

Comment: In fact, I use that trick, but the document looks like this [screen1](https://yadi.sk/i/RtaG7mT9LjMXRg), while I need it to look like that [screen2](https://yadi.sk/i/dCwVIub1RAzDOw). Thus, the table is rotated, but the whole page is not rotated visually like in the second screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand what  pdflscape.sty does and it's documentation doesn't say much. But based on the comments above, I guess what you want is the following:

```
\setuppapersize[A4,rotated][A4,landscape]
```

In the terminology of the context page layout, this rotates the `paper` and makes the `print` to be landscape.

Here is an example showing the result:

```
\setuppapersize[A4][A4]

\starttext

\input knuth

\page
\setuppapersize[A4,rotated][A4,landscape]
\input knuth
\page
\setuppapersize[A4][A4]
\input knuth
\page

\stoptext
```

Comment: Thank you, this works correctly for one-sided layout. For double-sided layout, this tends to odd and even pages rotated in *different* directions. In your setup, even pages are rotated as required for table heading to be horizontal, but odd pages appear to be upside-down. In case of usage \setuppapersize[A4,270][A4,landscape] odd pages have correct orientation, but even - upside-down one.